# Is it possible to render only specific scenes in solid viewport?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have a scene that includes many layers. I need a quick preview to see if the motion tracking worked fine in the scene. Is it possible to render only one scene in the compositor in solid viewport and the others in rendered?